# Serving brotli files from different root folder nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to serve brotli version of static html files from different folder in nginx? (Precompressed brotli versions)

Moreover I don’t want to put .html file in the same folder.

For example:

/home/br/test.html.br

/home/default/test.html